# SetParent(null) on a GameObject does not deallocate it?

Tags: memory-leaks, unity-game-engine

SetParent(null) on a GameObject does not deallocate it?

Is this common behaviour? I am porting a game from another engine and the general take on this kind of action in most environments is that if no one is the owner of the object, the object will soon be completely removed from memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `SetParent(null)` does not "deallocate" it.

If you want to remove it, you can call:

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

---

"Is this common behaviour?"

It varies from context to context. In Unity3D, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: If the object still exists, do you mean it won't take up any memory? I can clearly see that the `SetParent(null)`:ed objects in fact are moved to the root of the hierarchy, thus still existing. I did change some of those SetParent(null) to Destroy, and those objects disappeared as expected.

Comment: If they exist they take up memory unless you `Destroy()`, change scenes, or exit the game.